# Magento - How do I get a list of my custom attributes options?

Tags: magento

I want to get a list of my custom attributes' options, in order to create a menu of them.

The custom attribute is: nf_features and the label is Features.

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', '158');
foreach ( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) as $option){
echo $option['label']."<br>";
}
```